# Does YAML specification restricts the Kind for Custom Tags?

Tags: yaml, specifications

The YAML specification declares that a Tag must have an "expected" kind ([link](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#3212-tags)):

> YAML tags are used to associate meta information with each node. In particular, each tag must specify the expected node kind (scalar, sequence or mapping). Scalar tags must also provide a mechanism for converting formatted content to a canonical form for supporting equality testing. Furthermore, a tag may provide additional information such as the set of allowed content values for validation, a mechanism for tag resolution or any other data that is applicable to all of the tag’s nodes.

Kinds are of course any of Scalar, Mapping or Sequence. A tag will receive a bulk of Unicode characters, and parse them into it's custom logic natively.

I have 3 questions about the flexibility of Tags and their relationship with Kinds:

1. "Expected kind" means "Only one expected kind"?

   - In other words, could you implement a tag than can accept, and expect - both a mapping and a sequence?
   - For example, this will be accepted:

   ```
   this is a: !!very-kind-tag [1,2,3]
   so as this: !!very-kind-tag
     one: 1
     two: 2
     three: 3
   ```

   - If not, why? I can't see an explicit limitation
2. Changing the kind - Does the resulting node, after parsing it using the tag's native logic, can be from a different "kind" than the original ("expected") one?

   - To say, the parser reads `!!fullname Joe Smith` (scalar kind) and returns (or treats it, after custom tag's logic): `{first name: Joe, last name: Smith}` (a mapping)
3. "Expecting" a "Scalar" means to "expect a String"?

   - In other words, when parsing a character sequence for a Custom Tag, of course the raw input from YAML can be expected to be a collection of Unicode characters. When the node is "not tagged" (explicitly) it will be considered as a "string" in a way that applies all the string-related syntax (such as folding, multiline, etc). But, does the "scalar" kind, not the !!str tag, behaves the same?
   - For example: `Name: "Michael"` and `Name: Michael` (and also `Name: !!str Michael`) are mostly the same thing. But, is it possible to define a custom tag, expecting a scalar no problem, but will parse the characters in a custom way, different than the "string" parsing? eg, a Custom Tag that will make `Name: !!wow "Michael"` use the raw characters (including the quotes characters) instead of treat it as a regular string before.
   - If it's allowed and possible, where can I read about it?
   - According to some code examples related to the common `!!binary` custom tag, unfortunately I see they using the `|` character as used in the string tag. Is it integral?

Also, I'd love to know whether - Implementations in the wild:
In case the specification permit flexibility in Kinds in Tags, what does actually implemented in the common open-source libraries?

Answer (score 0):

> "Expected kind" means "Only one expected kind"?

The wording of the spec does not explicitly require this, other than in the part you quoted („scalar, sequence or mapping“), which can be read as exclusive or non-exclusive *or*.

More importantly, I do not know any implementation that enforces a certain kind for a custom tag. In most of them, particularly ones derived from PyYAML (e.g. SnakeYAML), you register a custom constructor for some tag and then get whatever kind of node has been tagged with this tag as input.

> Changing the kind - Does the resulting node, after parsing it using the tag's native logic, can be from a different "kind" than the original ("expected") one?

The specification only covers converting nodes in the context of testing them for equality. There is no step in the loading process where a node in the created graph would be changed in-place.

After you have loaded the YAML input into native data, the specification does not forbid you to serialize it into a different structure. So you are allowed to load `!!fullname Joe Smith` into a `struct { FirstName string; LastName String; }` and then serialize it as `{first name: Joe, last name: Smith}`.

> "Expecting" a "Scalar" means to "expect a String"?

*Scalar* is the YAML term for values that consist of unicode characters. These can be strings, but for example, `false` would usually be loaded as boolean. The spec says that values that do not have an explicit tag receive the non-specfic tag `?` which is to be resolved during the loading process to one of the supported tags of the used schema. So a non-tagged value `false` would be assigned the `!!bool` tag in the recommended schema while a non-tagged value `Michael` would be assigned the `!!str` tag. The values will then be processed as if they had the assigned tags as explicit tags.

Line folding, quoting, and other syntactic features work regardless of the scalar node's tag, so it is *not* restricted to `!!str`. Note however that the specification says that tag resolution on quoted values works differently (using the `!` non-specific tag) so that `"false"` will be assigned `!!str`. You can give `!!bool "false"` if you want to quote it but still load it as boolean. The syntactic features for YAML scalars (block scalars, escaped characters in double-quoted scalars etc) are applied *before* any tag processing takes place.

> If it's allowed and possible, where can I read about it?

The question you ask – „will characters in a non-!!str scalar be parsed differently“ is not explicitly answered in the spec but the answer I gave is implied by how the loading process is defined. *Parsing* is the process of transforming a character stream encoded in the YAML format into a list of events. Those are in the next step transformed into a node graph (resolving aliases). Only then will tags be of concern, in the resolution step, directly before constructing native values from the node graph. So the tags cannot possibly have an impact on scalar parsing because they are processed in a later step.

> According to some code examples related to the common !!binary custom tag, unfortunately I see they using the | character as used in the string tag. Is it integral?

A literal block scalar (starting with `|`) can be tagged as `!!binary`. `|` is a syntactic feature processed by the parser, it is not part of the tag. You can give a binary value in any other scalar form.

> Also, I'd love to know whether - Implementations in the wild: In case the specification permit flexibility in Kinds in Tags, what does actually implemented in the common open-source libraries?

The most common API (originally defined by PyYAML) is this:

- you register a custom tag with a callback. That callback takes a node as input and returns a constructed native value.
- some implementations additionally allow you to register a regex that will assign your custom tag to scalar nodes that match the regex. So for example you can set the regex `\d+d\d+` for custom tag `!dice` which will then be assigned to scalars like `3d20`. The custom tag then doesn't need to be given explicitly in the input (just like `false` would implicitly be tagged `!!bool`).
- likewise, you register a custom representer to transform your native values to YAML.

Some APIs deviate, particularly those of statically typed languages, which are less concerned with tags because they have static type information. For example, in go-yaml, you implement the interfaces `yaml.Marshaler` and `yaml.Unmarshaler` on the target type. Then, when you load YAML data into a value of that type, the interfaces' methods are called regardless of the YAML node's tag.

There is, to my knowledge, not one API that implements tagging and tag resolution exactly as it is described in the YAML spec (i.e. registering a tag with an explicitly given expected node kind).